# Placing a div after all the other stuff

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure given like below :

[image: page structure]

I am trying to place the highlighted div after the `div#content`

**A bit of background:**

I have the below style rule :

```
html,body{
position:relative;
top:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Also there are two nodes inside the `div#content` ie `div#node-1` & `div#node-2` and I have `height:100%` for both these elements. The idea
is to use these divisions as pages in the website which can be accessed
by scrolling down.

On applying the style rule, I get the below page.

[image: What I got]

I wanted to position the highlighted div at the very last ie after all the `div#content` stuff (The idea is to change it to footer later) but currently it is overlapping `div#content` (shown by the arrow). It appears between `div#content div#node-2` & `div#content div#node-1`.
I have no idea why this is happening. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit:**

See the sample jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryc4wu4v).

Comment: Add to your `div #content{ float:left; }`, maybe this can help

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I tried  replicated the problem using a similar structure, but the problem couldn't be reproduced. In fact in my simple document, things are working perfectly.

Comment: You have to be able to reproduce it.  If your simple example works, then maybe there's an issue in your markup in the full site.  Have you run it through the W3C Validator?

Comment: @MarioKurzweil : I will put a sample JSFiddle which is working perfectly just to explain my idea.

Comment: @cale_b :  I just validated the file via W3C Valdator and it is fine except for the document type. This is just a drupal `page.tpl.php` with minimal html code. So I have not included the html and the body tags when I checked.

Comment: A temporary workaround is to put the highlighted division just after `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`  in page.tpl.php.